# Read MS Excel file via JavaScript or php and write to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, xml, excel, mongodb, xls

I need to write a web application. The user will select the excel file from the open file dialog box. The application should be able to read the data from specific cells in excel file, and write them into mongodb.

Any ideas how to implement reading and writing?

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't say what programming language you're using on the web server where you'd need to parse the Excel files. I'd start with an Internet search for `reading excel files in <language>`.

Comment: uh, right.. well, JS preferably, or php. I will edit the caption

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xlsx+php

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, there are libraries to read [XLS](https://github.com/Niggler/js-xls) and [XLSX](https://github.com/Niggler/js-xlsx) files, both of which give you cell-level access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple format of data in the Excel file (like a table of cells), you can use [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library. It also uses [XLSX.js](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library under the hood.

This is an example to use MongoDB with Alasql+XLSX.js to read Excel into JSON array and write it into MongoDB database.

```
var alasql = require('alasql');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection('mydata');
   // Read Excel file to array of JSON objects
    alasql('SELECT * FROM XLSX("mydata.xlsx", \
            {headers:true, sheetid:"Sheet2",range:"A1:D100"})',[],function(data){

        collection.insert(data);  // Write array to MongoDB here
        db.close();
    });
});
```